# OverflowError on scipy optimize when using multiprocessing

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, multiprocessing

I am trying to parallelize the fitting of a large dataset. I did an atomic test on a single array and it worked. When I introduced multiprocessing the model started to show overflowerror.

```
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy import optimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def math_model(n):
    def crrn(x, t0, amp, tau, offset):
        crrn = np.zeros(np.shape(x))
        for i,a in enumerate(x):
            if a < t0:
                crrn[i] = offset
            else: 
                crrn[i] = offset + amp * (math.exp(n) / (n ** n)) * \
                ((a - t0) / tau) ** n * math.exp( - (a - t0) / tau)
        return crrn
    return crrn

def fitting_model (d, X, p) :
    model = math_model(8)
    errfunc = lambda p, x, y: model(x, *p) - y
    p1, success = optimize.leastsq(errfunc, p, args=(X, d))
    residuo = model(X, *p1) - y
    return p1, residuo

y = [48.9375, 50.0, 49.9375, 50.0, 49.9375, 49.0, 50.9375, 52.0, 53.9375, 56.0, 56.9375,
 58.0, 59.9375, 61.0, 61.9375, 60.0, 59.9375, 58.0, 55.9375, 55.0, 52.9375,
 53.0, 50.9375, 51.0, 49.9375, 49.0, 48.9375, 49.0, 47.9375, 49.0, 48.9375, 48.0]
x = list(range(len(y)))
p = [4,12,2,47]
p, resudio = fitting_model (y, x, p)
```

That is the working example. The following is with multiprocessing added.

```
def fitting_worker(data, params):
    model = math_model(params[0])
    X = list(range(len(data[0])))
    fit = []
    residuals = []
    errfunc = lambda p, x, y: model(x, *p) - y 
    for d in data:
        p, success = optimize.leastsq(errfunc, params[1:], args=(X, d))
        fit.append(p)
        residuals.append(model(X, *p) - d)
    return [fit, residuals]

def fitting(data, params):
    processors = mp.cpu_count()
    pool = mp.Pool(processors)
    fitted = []
    numlines = math.floor(len(data) / processors) * 3
    fitted = pool.map(partial(fitting_worker, params = params),
                      (data[line : line + numlines] for line in range(0, len(data), numlines)))
    pool.close()
    return [item for sublist in fitted for item in sublist]
```

Added a try, except to see if the data was provoking this but trying with the data that triggered the error in multiprocessing in the single process file works fine. If you have any suggestion on how to solve this it would be great. Thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not advised to use leastsq. The function to use is curve_fit which relies on leastsq but fixes most of leastsq issues.